# Selecting distinct value for specified date

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017

This is my very first post on stackoverflow:)

I would like to ask you for help with my query. I would like to have only distinct value in col1 (SetDate),  for duplicate values, I'd like to take the value with the higher date in column 2 (QuoDate). For example  for SetDate = 2020-01-08 I would like to show only QuoDate = 2020-01-06 and MidPrice=4.2422.

```
SetDate     QuoDate     MidPrice
2019-12-30  2019-12-24  4.2539
2019-12-30  2019-12-26  4.257
2019-12-31  2019-12-27  4.2627
2020-01-02  2019-12-30  4.2602
2020-01-03  2019-12-31  4.2531
2020-01-07  2020-01-02  4.2513
2020-01-08  2020-01-03  4.2443
2020-01-08  2020-01-06  4.2422
2020-01-09  2020-01-07  4.2452
2020-01-10  2020-01-08  4.2389
2020-01-13  2020-01-09  4.2431
2020-01-14  2020-01-10  4.2408
```

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Comment: Hi, I am using SQL Server 2017.

Answer (score 1):

You can use row_number() to understand, which row is the last in SetDate partition:

```
select
 t.SetDate
,t.QuoDate
,t.MidPrice
from (
 select
  t.SetDate
 ,t.QuoDate
 ,t.MidPrice
 ,row_number() over (partition by t.SetDate order by t.QuoDate desc) as RN_SetDate
 from t_data t
) t
where t.RN_SetDate = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do what you want using a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.quodate = (select max(t2.quodate)
                   from t t2
                   where t2.setdate = t.setdate
                  );
```

For performance, you want an index on `(setdate, quodate)`.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=ab0542237a611cef65f7d8067cb4a827) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Hi, thank for your reply. Unfortunately your solution is not working properly in my case. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: @PiotrDS . . . I added a db<>fiddle.  It seems to be doing what you are asking for.

Comment: @ Gordon Linoff I see that on db<>fiddle. it’ working perfectly exactly as I expected, but when I try to run It on my Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2017 I receive only one value with the highest QuoDate.

Comment: Here you might look at my query: https://share.icloud.com/photos/0GLFD0nhr0SOUxkdNK7V5PkfA